# Extracting data from set,update and add method-

Tags: firebase

Can anyone tell me that how we can extract data from add, update and set method-
such as:-

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

//1.
resturant = await db.collection("resturants").doc(resId).set({
        name,
        locations,
        address,
        resPhoneNumber,
        contact,
        email,
        contactPhoneNumber,
      });

//2.
resturant = await db.collection("resturants").add({
        name,
        locations,
        address,
        resPhoneNumber,
        contact,
        email,
        contactPhoneNumber,
      });

//3.
resturant = await db.collection("resturants").doc(resId).update({
        operationHours,
      });
```

In all of scnerios i'm not able to get actual saved data from above resturant variable0

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't provide a callback with complete data which is set to the document instead it provides document reference when you add new data.

Hence, You will need to query again to get the data or you can bind the listener to the collection which will listen to updated results and give a callback.

Other than if you want data after your set or update operations you can listen for success in `.then()` and re-query to updated records.

While you perform `.add()` with data. You will get document ref (as shown below) with document id through which You can get the available data.

```js
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
```

Ref - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document